# Statically initializing constexpr std::array of objects containing function pointers

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to statically initialize a constexpr std::array of objects containing function pointers with the following code:

```
#include <array>

using TVoidVoid = void(*)(void);

class State{
public:
  constexpr State(TVoidVoid function) : function_{function}{}
private:
  TVoidVoid function_;
};

void OnEvent1(){}
void OnEvent2(){}
constexpr std::array<State, 10> states = {{OnEvent1}, {OnEvent2}};

int main(){}
```

I am compiling with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ -Wstrict-aliasing -ansi -pedantic -Werror -std=c++14 main.cpp
```

I have trouble understanding the compiling error I'm getting:

```
main.cpp:14:69: error: too many initializers for ‘const std::array<State, 10>’
 constexpr std::array<State, 10> states = {{OnEvent1}, {OnEvent2}}
```

The  compiler is g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0.

What could be the problem here? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a default constructor (for the last 8)

```
#include <array>

using TVoidVoid = void(*)(void);

class State{
public:
  // This static is equivalent to a TVoidVoid
  // used by the default constructor
  static void DefFunct() {}

  constexpr State(TVoidVoid function) : function_{function}{}

  // We create a default constructor for the 
  // empty elemnts of the array with our function
  constexpr State() : function_(DefFunct) {}

private:
  TVoidVoid function_;
};

void OnEvent1(){}
void OnEvent2(){}
constexpr std::array<State, 10> states = {OnEvent1, OnEvent2};

int main(){}
```

Comment: Thanks Mirko, I reformulated the question, but the code remains the same: I need an array of objects containing function pointers. I would like to construct these objects of type State in-place in the array.

Comment: @MihaiGalos Edited the answer.

Comment: So the remaining items need to be default-constructed, which was producing the error. Of course. All elements are  statically constructed. Awesome. Please remove the first answer and leave the one after the edit, perhaps add a few comments why this is needed. Then we can close this question! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error message could be better. But what's tripping the initialization is in fact that you don't have enough braces. Recall that a `std::array` is an aggregate wrapping a raw array. So you need to initialize like this:

```
constexpr std::array<State, 10> states = {{ {OnEvent1}, {OnEvent2} }};
```

Otherwise, the somewhat inaccurate brace ellision detection algorithm assumes `{OnEvent1}` is to initialize the internal array, and the second clause is redundant.

Now you just need to provide a default c'tor for `State`, or adjust the array size.

Comment: thank you! I did not know I needed a default constructor for the the non-default initialized elements.

Comment: @Mihai - Each c'tor is a different way to initialize objects of your class. The first two don't need it. It's the rest. You can also provide it in another way. `TVoidVoid function = nullptr` will make your existing c'tor usable as a default c'tor too.

Comment: I'm a bit amazed that with extra {} (StoryTeller answer) and with less {} works too (my answer), but with the original quantity it did not.

Comment: @Mirko - Initialization in C++ is crazy, sadly.